# Image cannot be added to the ImageList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.ImageList` "_imageList".
Below is my sample code.

```
_imageList.ColorDepth = System.Windows.Forms.ColorDepth.Depth8Bit;

Image imageStamp;
int imgCount = 5000
for( int idx = 0; idx < imgCount; idx++ )
{
   imageStamp = Image.FromFile(filename);
   _imageList.Images.Add( imageResult[idx].Key, imageStamp );
   imageStamp.Dispose();
   imageStamp = null;

}
```

But after loading over 4000 images, I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` "Image cannot be added to the ImageList". The stack trace is as below.

```
at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.AddToHandle(Original original, Bitmap bitmap)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.Add(Original original, ImageInfo imageInfo)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.Add(String key, Image image)
```

How do I resolve this?

During this operation my process's **memory** usage was ~**114,872K** and **Handles** was ~**1031**. Checked using Windows taskmanager.
When I use Reflector to check the code in `ImageList` ,

```
private int AddToHandle(Original original, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    IntPtr monochromeMask = ControlPaint.CreateHBitmapTransparencyMask(bitmap);
    IntPtr handle = ControlPaint.CreateHBitmapColorMask(bitmap, monochromeMask);
    int num = SafeNativeMethods.ImageList_Add(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), new HandleRef(null, handle), new HandleRef(null, monochromeMask));
    SafeNativeMethods.DeleteObject(new HandleRef(null, handle));
    SafeNativeMethods.DeleteObject(new HandleRef(null, monochromeMask));
    if (num == -1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ImageListAddFailed"));
    }
    return num;
}
```

If I modify above for loop to use `Dictionary<string, Image>` instead of `ImageList`, 5000 images(may be more images) can be added to the Dictionary without any error.

```
for( int idx = 0; idx < imgCount; idx++ )
{
   imageStamp = Image.FromFile(filename);
   // _imageList.Images.Add( imageResult[idx].Key, imageStamp );
   // imageStamp.Dispose();
   // imageStamp = null;
   _imageListDictionary.Add( imageResult[idx].Key, imageStamp );
}
```

Is this the limitation of `ImageList` ?
I need to show more than 10,000 (count depends) images in my `ListView` (`ListView.View = View.Tile`). If `ImageList` has limitation, how can I make it without using a `ImageList` ?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace along with line that causes the error.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180954/imagelist-capacity-bug-in-net-imagelist-implementation

Comment: @techno: The line ` _imageList.Images.Add( imageResult[idx].Key, imageStamp );` causes error. Rest is in stack trace.

Comment: why do you set `imageStamp = null;` even after disposing it?

Comment: Where is this populated 'imageResult'. Are you sure it has a valid value in the array for 4000 +

Comment: @James Dev: Yes. It is valid. This exception is thrown from `ImageList`

Comment: During this operation my process's **memory** usage was **114,872k** and **Handles** was **1031**. Checked using Windows taskmanager.

Comment: Is it always the same image it happens at? What happens if you add _only that image_?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Not same image. It is with the image count and image size. For large sized images, exception occures @ 3000 some thing

Comment: @Kaizen did you check the GDI objects? (should be available on task manager, details view, select column). The default both per-process and shared in Windows is 10,000 IIRC... you may be near that limit. The limit can be raised using the registry though

Comment: @Jcl  checked the GDI objects of my process and it is 303.

Comment: ImageList is a clunky control, it is only suitable to act as the image source for a ListView or TreeView.  It uses precious storage, the desktop heap is a limited resource that all processes that run on the desktop must share.  A couple of hundred of images is reasonable upper limit to consider, you are way beyond that.